# error routing failure in biztalk server 2010

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I want to receive data from SOL and transfer the data to FILE, I used  WCF-SQL and an error routing failure appear on starting. I configured SQL binding and poll data

Is this adapter adapter compatible?

Comment: Please provide more information to allow others to understand your problem. What's the specific error for example?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you haven't created a Send Port that subscribes to messages coming from your WCF-SQL Receive Port/Location.

You need to create a new Send Port with a File Adapter and specify a Filter as follows:

- BTS.ReceivePortName == [YOUR RECEIVE PORT NAME]

Both the Receive Location and Send Port will need to use the PassThruReceive/PassThruSend Pipelines, unless you have defined a Schema for the SQL message.

Finally, start the Send Port and try polling your SQL Database again; the message returned by the WCF-SQL adapter should be written to the location configured within your File Adapter.

Please bear in mind that the message written out probably won't be in the format that you require. To resolve that, you will need to create a Map, however this way beyond the scope of this question :-)

Comment: dear Nick,i already a send port and i specify a filter :( and i set passThrue anad he did'nt work

Comment: if i use filter the data will not pass through the orchestration,i want to use the orchestration not directly from receive port to send port,any solution?